# Odoo Internal Server Error

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

My Odoo platform was working great, since i decided to uninstall the accounting module since i was not using it.

After doing the installation it's not opening more and it's giving 500 internal server error.

Full logs are here: https://justpaste.it/wrsj

So what to do in order to solve this issue?

Comment: do you have any custom module that's related to the accounting module?

Comment: No, but i have custom fields that was related to analytical accounts.. i was not able to access the system to install the module again.. so i copied the table of the analytical account and all tables related to the account module manually to the database.. but still nothing working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the custom module or move it somewhere else.. and restart the server..

As per your log move the accounting module and hr_holiday module and restart the server. Then in apps search your module and click on cancel install, then again add the accounting module.

Comment: i followed this, and there's was many other hidden issues, some views was calling some field that were deleted..

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways by which server can crash.

***Some are listed below***

•   If the changes made in a pre-existing module is not correctly formatted.

•   More than two fields with a single name are created and forcefully saved in the same model.

•   Model and views are not binded properly etc.

***So how to overcome issues.***

•   We can go to the files in which we made changes and undo them.

•   We can go to our database through pg admin and delete the field which is crashing the server.

•   Most effective way to find an error is that we can check odoo.log file. Location Odoo-> Server-> odoo.log.

•   We can hit the URL and revert back on to our previously saved database and resume our work from there. URL- http://localhost:8069/web/database/selector